# Which scripture classifies the 18 mahapuranas based on the three gunas (sattva, tamas and rajas)?

Tags: puranas, identification-request, gunas

We all know that there are 18 Mahapuranas and have also heard that 6 each are categorized in different gunas - sattva, tamas and rajas.

I would like to know the reference if any of the purana or upanishad describe the 18 mahapuranas and also the source of the guna-categorization of the 18 puranas?

It would help to give the exact reference and if possible kindly give the relevant sanskrit text.

Comment: first part is duplicate, u should stick to classification only...

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

The Padma Purana classifies the 18 Mahapuranas according to the gunas.

> The Padma Purana classifies these texts according to the three Gunas
>   and ascribes them to one or the other principal deity. Thus the
>   ***Vishnu***, ***Narada***, ***Bhagavata***, ***Garuda***, ***Padma***, and ***Varaha***, are Vishnuite
>   **sattvika** Puranas, and as such **lead to salvation**; the ***Brahmanda***,
>   ***Brahmavaivarta***, ***Markendeya***, ***Bhavisya***, ***Vamana***, and ***Brahma*** are the
>   **rajasa** texts devoted to Brahman and **secure only heaven** for their
>   readers; lastly the ***Matsya***, ***Kurma***, ***Linga***, ***Siva***, ***Skanda***, and ***Agni*** are
>   Saivite and styled as **tamas**. It is surprising to note that these
>   **latter are regared as leading to hell**.

**The History and Culture of the Indian People, The Classical Age, Chapter XV, Literature, The Puranas, edited by R. C. Majumdar**

I am unable to give the exact reference or the relevant Sanskrit text.

Comment: Thank you. I also found the following [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=DgMxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR12&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) which states that its the Uttara-khanda which classifies it and also here we find that Matsya purana also mentions about the 18 Mahapuranas and their classification. Also it states more or less all the Mahapuranas state about other 18 mahapuranas.